# C language macro which writes the port

Tags: c, io, macros, embedded, port

Suppose that IO-part is memory mapped to address 0x32 and the directive defines

```
#define portx 0x32
```

How to construct C language macro which writes the port by storing a value to corresponding register?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31266754/584518) for another duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

If you must use a macro then typically it would be something like this:

```
#define WRITE_PORT(port, val) *((volatile uint8_t *)(port)) = (val)
```

and you might then invoke this as, e.g.

```
WRITE_PORT(portx, 0xff);  // write 0xff to portx
```

Note that this assumes an 8 bit port.

Note also the use of `volatile`, to prevent I/O reads/writes from being optimised away by the compiler.

Comment: what is val? is *((volatile uint8_t *)(port)) the address of port mapped IO?

Comment: `val` is the second macro parameter, i.e. the value that will be written to the port. `*((volatile uint8_t *)(port))` simply casts the numeric port address to a pointer and then de-references that pointer in order to write to the address it points at.

Comment: ok, thanks! so if  IO-part is memory mapped to address 0x32 and the directive defines #define portx 0x32 the macro would be #define WRITE_PORT(port, val)

Comment: ok, thanks! so if  IO-part is memory mapped to address 0x32 and the directive defines #define portx 0x32 the macro would be #define WRITE_PORT(port, val) 0x32 = (val)  ?

Comment: Um, no, the whole point of making `port` and `val` parameters of the macro is that you can use the same macro with any port and any val. In your case you'd just invoke it as e.g. `WRITE_PORT(portx, 0xff);`, which would write `0xff` to the 8 bit port at memory address `0x32`.

Comment: ok, this is now clear for me! thank you very much Paul :)

Comment: just to make sure: is the macro in my case #define WRITE_PORT(portx, val) *((volatile uint8_t *)(0x32)) = (val)

Comment: No, you've changed it from that is written above in the answer: `port` and `val` are *parameters*. The macro is meant to be *generic*, so you can pass any port address and any value. In your specific case you pass `portx` and whatever value you want to write to that port, as in the example I gave in the answer.

Comment: Ok, so I don't need to mention to 0x32 in the macro?

Comment: No, you don't need to mention 0x32, or portx, or anything specific in the macro itself - good programming practice is is write things in a generic way, so that they can be re-used without modification.

Comment: thank you for your explanations and help!

Comment: No problem - just take exactly what's written in the answer and make sure you fully understand every detail.